# How to make an ajax request in ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Hello I am new to ruby on rails I have just started to learn. I would like to know how can I make the ajax request.
My js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form_submit").click(function() {
         var apiid = $('#apiid').val();
         var apikey = $('#apikey').val();
         var email = $('#email').val();
           console.log("apiid  = ",apiid , " apikey = ",apikey , " email = ",email);

  });  
});
```

Now I want to send apiid , apikey and email to my controller.

```
def api 
//here I want apiid, apikey,email from js
end
```

Comment: There is a lot of tutorials and guides in the internet, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've sent the data to your server via js with something like

```
$.post("/your/url",
{
    apiid: "1",
    apikey: "1",
    email: "some@email.com"
});
```

Then you can access these parameters in your controller via the params hash:

```
def api
  params[:apiid]
  params[:apikey]
  params[:email]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have you RESTful API setup on your Rails Server, then all you would have to do is send the Ajax request. If you haven't done that, this tutorial will teach you how to do it.

https://www.codementor.io/ruby-on-rails/tutorial/creating-simple-api-with-rails

After that all you have to do is:

```
$.post("/path/to/url",
{
    apiid: "1",
    apikey: "1",
    email: "some@email.com"
},
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

The first parameter is the route endpoint, the second parameter is your json data, and the third parameter is a callback function that is executed when the server is done executing it's update.

Answer (score 1):

You can set apiid, apikey and email in hidden field or can assign in the formData properties later.
All data here is grab from form. the url is the form action, method is an action set in form.

Note: `.form_submit` is a class of form not button.

```
$( '.form_submit' ).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var remoteCall = new RemoteCall(this);
    remoteCall.ajax()
  })
function RemoteCall(element){
  this.url = element.action;
  this.method = element.method;
  this.dataType = 'json';
  this.formData = $(element).serialize()
}
RemoteCall.prototype.ajax = function(){
    $.ajax({ method: this.method,
             url: this.url,
             data: this.formData,
             dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function(msg){
             alert('done'); 
          }).fail(function(msg){ alert('Sorry request could not complete'); });
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I want to know that how to get the bring the data in the controller like in php we use `$_POST['apiid']` to get the data so here in ruby how can we get the data in controller ?

Comment: To access submitted form data in controller you can use params. for an example if you send post request as apiid: 'sad' by ajax. you can access as params[:apiid]. If you are not aware about what actual is the field name you can inspect params to view all the form data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) option `data` to send the params in an ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form_submit").click(function() {
    var apiid = $('#apiid').val();
    var apikey = $('#apikey').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

    $.ajax(path_to_api_action, {
      data: { apiid: apiid, apikey: apikey, email: email }
      // Add other options
    })
  });  
});
```