# Appending items to array in a cookie in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

So I need to store an array of ID's inside a cookie.

I've created this function to append id's to the cookie. This code is my  scotlands_controller.rb

```
def add_to_cookie (id)
  if cookies[:scotids].size == 0
    cookies[:scotsids] = JSON.generate(["#{id}"])
    puts "id #{id} was added to the cookie"
  else
    cookies[:scotsids] = JSON.parse(cookies[:scotsids]) << "#{id}"
  puts "id #{id} was added to the cookie"
end
```

What I want to do is display a button next to items displayed on a table that invoke that function so that I later on read the ID's from the array, kind of like a shopping cart.

How do I call that function from my view? Can it be done without reloading the page?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Calling that method on the controller (probably `scotlands_controller.rb`) and using that value on the view is not an option??

Comment: No cos I neet to call it many times to collect all the ids and manipulate the array later on in another view

Comment: And you need to call that method more than one time in a view?

Comment: Yes, I am displaying a list of items and each item will have a button next to it saying "Add To Comparison", so every time that button gets clicked I want to call that function to append the item ID to the array in the cookie.

Comment: Do you know something about AJAX? that is what you need to do that (Im not good in AJAX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an action in controller, next you need how to route to that action from the view. Do you understand?

What you need to do is add a route to routes.rb file. Something like:

```
post "/add_item_to_cookie   => "scotlands_controller/add_to_cookie"
```

You need to get exactly the item's id and pass it as a Ajax's params.

How to use AJAX call to prevent browser to refresh whole page at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261089/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-in-ruby-on-rails)